# Apple Scriptで開いたウインドウに存在するボタンを押下したい。

Tags: macos, applescript

ワイヤレス診断（Wireless Diagnostics.app）を起動し、⌘ + 6 で別ウインドウを開くスクリプトを書きました。「スニファ」という名前の別ウインドウが開き、ウインドウ内の"開始"ボタンを押下したいのですが、ボタン押下の部分がうまく動かず困っております。

```
 tell application "Wireless Diagnostics"
activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "6" using {command down}
end tell

tell application "System Events"
tell process "Wireless Diagnostics"
    click button "開始" of window "スニファ"
end tell
end tell
```

エラー

```
button "開始" of window "スニファ" of application process "Wireless Diagnostics" of application "System Events"
```

[image: エレメント]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記の通りウインドウを指定することで、クリックすることができました。

tell application "Wireless Diagnostics"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "6" using {command down}
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Wireless Diagnostics"
        click button "開始" of window 1
        delay 10
        click button "中止" of window 1
    end tell
end tell